# Twilio Task Router - Evaluate task attributes based on age

Tags: twilio, twilio-taskrouter

In Twilio Task router, how to evaluate task based on age. For one of requirement where customer is asking to call after 5 minutes, so in task router, how can enforce task assignment after 5 minutes, not immediately.

i.e. task.age > 300. I have tried this in workflow, however task is assigned to staff member immediately.

Any help around this would be useful.

Comment: Are you asking how to delay a task for 5 minutes?

Comment: Yes, task assignment should be done after 5 minute not immediately.

Comment: I've not tried this, but what happens if you place the task into a queue that has no workers assigned and a timeout of 5 minutes?